# Custom error page in Apache2 for 401

Tags: apache, apache2, custom-error-pages

Here's the relevant part of the .htaccess file:

```
AuthUserFile  /var/www/mywebsite/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName  protected
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user

ErrorDocument 400 /var/www/errors/index.html
ErrorDocument 401 /var/www/errors/index.html
ErrorDocument 403 /var/www/errors/index.html
ErrorDocument 404 /var/www/errors/index.html
ErrorDocument 500 /var/www/errors/index.html
```

Docuement root is set to /var/www/mywebsite/web, it's on of many vhosts.  I can navigate to the index.html page.

All I'm seeing is the generic Apache 401 page, any thoughts.

EDIT: This is the error message in my browser:

> Authorization Required
>
> This server could not verify that you
>   are authorized to access the document
>   requested. Either you supplied the
>   wrong credentials (e.g., bad
>   password), or your browser doesn't
>   understand how to supply the
>   credentials required.
>
> Additionally, a 401 Authorization
>   Required error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to
>   handle the request. Apache/2.2.9
>   (Debian) PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny8 with
>   Suhosin-Patch Server at www.dirbe.com
>   Port 80

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that /var/www/errors is readable by the apache user and include this in your apache configuration:

```
<Directory /var/www/errors>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: No luck. And nothing in any of the error logs.  I am seeing this on the error page though: "Additionally, a 401 Authorization Required error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: Try putting your require auth lines inside of a <Location /></Location> section.

Comment: thanks for the hint, but no avail.  Got an error: <Location not allowed here

Comment: The apache documentation says that ErrorDocument can be a path relative to the document root, or an external URL that will be sent with a redirect. Since you're getting an Auth required message you might need two adjacent directories, one at /errors, and one at /protected, where the .htaccess in /protected would reference /errors/401.html as the ErrorDocument.

Comment: Sam's last comment solved my issue, so I've accepted his original answer.

Comment: I just came across this thread, and after reading Apache docs found out that "ErrorDocument not just CAN be a path relative to the document root but MUST be a relative to DocumentRoot. Seems no way to put those ErrorDocs out of the DR directory.

Comment: In other words, the `ErrorDocument`, if it's a path, is _not_ a file path but a [URL path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Definition), and that path must be accessible like a normal document (e.g. in the `DocumentRoot`). This is because the `ErrorDocument` directive does just a simple _redirect_. The chosen answer above (using `Directory`) is misleading and only correct in combination with an appropriate `DocumentRoot` configuration and (optional) specification of a `VirtualHost` block.

Answer (score 4):

ErrorDocument takes in a absolute URL path instead of a file path. So it should be:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/error.html
```

Assuming under your document root is a /error/error.html file.

Comment: This should be the chosen answer. The important bit is, "[URL path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Definition)". Don't mistake it for a _file_ path!

Comment: Also make sure the file at this location is accessible like a "normal" document (e.g. just like `index.html` in your `DocumentRoot`). This is because the `ErrorDocument` directive does a simple _redirect_, no direct reading of the (file or) location.

Answer (score 3):

This question (and answers and comments) helped me a bunch, thanks much!

I solved a slightly different way, and wanted to share. In this case, we needed to provide a custom 401 error document and the root path needed to be proxied to a backend app.

So, for example, http://example.com needed to serve content from http://internal-server:8080/. Also, http://example.com needed to be protected using Basic Auth with a custom 401 error document.

So, I created a directory named "error" in the DocumentRoot. Here's the relevant lines from the vhost:

```
    ErrorDocument 401 /error/error401.html

    # Grant access to html files under /error
<Location "/error">
Options -Indexes
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
</Location>

    # restrict proxy using basic auth
<Proxy *>
Require valid-user
AuthType basic
AuthName "Basic Auth"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
</Proxy>

    # Proxy everything except for /error
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /error !
ProxyPass / http://internal:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://internal:8080/
```

Comment: Tried this, but i'm getting the error page before asking to login.
Any ideas?