# URL not redirected to 404 page in J2EE application

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, http-status-code-404

If I mess with the file name in the URL it doesn’t redirect to 404 pageFor example.

```
       http://10.2.3.22/xyz/404ewewqewqe.html  - This url does not work
       http://10.2.3.22/xyz/404, These 3 urls works fine 
       http://10.2.3.22/xyz/404ewqewqe,http://10.2.3.22/xyeewewqeweollows -
```

In Apache httpd file i have following entry as follows - 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
Any help or pointer would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of understand your problem but why not use the Web.xml :

```
<error-page>
   <exception-type>404</exception-type>
   <location>/404error.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Be careful with servlet version : [How to specify the default error page in web.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066192/how-to-specify-the-default-error-page-in-web-xml)

I use :

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException</exception-type>
    <location>/app/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

I hope this could help you.

Comment: This set up has been configured in such a way that we cannot move this to web.xml. Do you see any issue with Apache error document configuration to handle this behavior.

Comment: The syntax is simple and seems correct..
Isn't it a right problem ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341263/custom-error-page-in-apache2-for-401